# Clear an array with empty elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I wrote the object as the second element in the array, and then sorted it. As a result, we got an array of one object and two empty values, which are not indicated in any way. 
It looks like this: `[{...}, empty × 2]`
How can I clean it?

My code

```
for (i = 0; i < data.Levels.length; i++) {
        $.each(data.Ranges, function() {
            for (var property in this) {
                if (this[property][i] != 0) {
                    isNullable = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isNullable) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (!isNullable) {
            levels[i] = { //Writing object
                Level: data.Levels[i],
                Position: i
            };
        }
    }
levels.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.Level < b.Level) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.Level > b.Level) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: please add the code. what do you mean by *clean*?

Comment: @NinaScholz 
I have one object and two empty elements in the array, I want that there would be one object

Comment: sorry, i do not understand. please add what you did.

Comment: If you're not going to post the code that can reproduce the problem, then the question is off-topic and will be closed

Comment: Why did you make a sparse array to begin with? Usually you want to avoid those entirely, not convert them after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new elements to the end of the array with [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), avoiding creating a sparse array entirely:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.Levels.length; i++) {
    $.each(data.Ranges, function() {
        for (var property in this) {
            if (this[property][i] != 0) {
                isNullable = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isNullable) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!isNullable) {
        levels.push({ //Writing object
            Level: data.Levels[i],
            Position: i
        });
    }
}
```